What are the real benefits of zero drop running shoes?
I have this struggle every time I go to look for new running shoes. Do zero drop shoes really help with running form? From what I understand you need to a toe striker to wear them - is this true?

Not sufficient as an answer, but I like zero drop running shoes, but I have noticed that most zero-drop shoes have relatively little cushioning.  I have some low (but not zero) drop cushioned shoes and they seem a lot more like any other running shoes than most of my zero drop ones.  I find they make it easier to run on my mid- fore-foot as I can feel better how my foot is landing.  This is especially true for minimalist shoes ("foot gloves").  Fully agree with @PhilipKlocking about having a variety of running shoes.

Just to add, you don't need to be a toe-striker to use zero-drop shoes, I use them and am aiming for a mid-foot strike and they work well for that for me.

@DikranMarsupial Dunno and certainly don't want to go into the rabbit hole of discussions about strikes but mid-foot strike seems both unnatural and inefficient from a biomechanical perspective since the anterior lower leg muscles are essentially without function with short surface contact times and unnecessarily big height oscillation without taking full advantage of our biggest energy saver, which is loading the achilles tendon (up to 60% of locomotion energy can be done solely by that). Thus, I just don't buy it.

@PhilipKlöcking interesting, I'll have a think about that.  If I am sprinting, then I do have a forefoot landing, but that doesn't seem maintainable for longer runs and midfoot doesn't feel unnatural for me.  It could be that as my tendon/muscle strength improves my striking will become increasingly fore-footed.  I do seem to have a lot of ankle mobility and long Achilles tendons which may also be an issue (not good for energy storage?).  My running dynamics pod suggests I have a reasonable vertical oscillation (7.7cm on my last run), but anything to improve my running efficiency!

@DikranMarsupial A repetitive high-intensity (around 85% of max) loading scheme (3-6s loading, 3-6 second unloaded, 15 sets of 4 per week over at least 12 weeks) for your triceps surae can significantly increase the stiffness and loading capacity (bot the length!) of your Achilles tendon

Many thanks @PhilipKlöcking - I'll add that to my gym routine (as well as the high-rep body weight calf-raises that I already do).  To clarify, the tendons are so long I basically can't stretch them - even though I have a lot of ankle mobility the joint reaches its range of motion before the tendon is really stretched, which I suspect is not ideal for running.  However I think they are also weak (I did partially rupture one about 20 years ago).

@DikranMarsupial Tendon stretching isn't a thing, actually. In other words: They gain some elasticity in plyometric training that is temporary (warming up, anyone?) but there is no way to elongate them but by way of rupture since the contractile elements (muscle) give way much easier and longer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Some remarks on shoe type choices and rationales in general
According to my physio education, the choice of drop, zero drop, of even incline should depend on the ratio between ankle height and heel length, the higher the more the tendency should go to zero drop or even incline. That is very old bio-mechanical speculation-type voodoo stuff and not scientifically substantiated as far as I know, though.
Thus, as long as you have the active ankle mobility, try it. I want to emphasise that the drop is mainly due to the cushion we need for the heel in our impact phase when we do normal strides on hard surfaces, though. Toe strikes make sense in this context when we run without cushion on hard surfaces and the higher cadence resulting from it might have a positive impact on some problems like runner's knee but puts more stress on the middle foot. Your running style will adapt anyways because, well...running with long strides on concrete without heel cushion hurts, you know?
What training parameters you have to have in mind when changing your (running) shoe type
Generally, it is advised to run in different-type shoes sometimes and not have too high a volume with any type of shoe your structures are not adapted to. Therefore, if you're a hobby runner with, say, 25k a week, you should do 5k a week with a completely new shoe (type) at max and progress slowly (like 10% a week) to give your structures time to adapt to the new stimulus.
Thinking about it, the toe strikes put a much higher stress on the Achilles tendon besides the middle foot. I have heard of many cases where changing to zero drop shoes started to end in some kind of Achilles tendon related pain. Since tendons do not respond much to plyometric stress with adaptation (since the stress is too short to elicit a biochemical reaction) but still experience the stress damages that come with it, some sort of calf strength program (similar to Achilles tendon rehab programs) should accompany the change to this kind of shoe to avoid possible adaptation problems. It will help to enhance the ability of the tendon to withstand stress.
What are the real benefits, now?
Basically, it conditions your lower limb structures in a different way than other kinds of shoes do, ie. the arch of the foot and other structures experience training stimuli they would not with other shoes. As I mentioned earlier, it may mitigate some stress reactions like runner's knee and shin splints due to different biomechanics including less heel contact, shorter strides, and higher cadence.

wow thank you! this was really helpful!

@KelseyJackson - Also realize that a lot of the Pose, Chi running styles (High cadence, up on toes only) came out of a very limited review of elite (Olympic level) runners in the middle of a race. Heel striking does not necessarily mean that the heel touches first. It's what portion of the foot is bearing the most weight when your center of gravity passes over it. My heel touches first, but my midfoot is where my COG passes over the foot. I've run 1000's of miles (College x-country) with shin splints once when my shoes wore out. Find what works for you.

@JohnP Dunno, when doing running analyses, the Initial Contact phase with the heel means the anterior muscles around the shin have to slow the fall of the foot down while you literally roll down your posterior calcaneus bone (ie. heel). That is a lot of stress on the aponeurosis between fibula and tibia bone as well as the heel, especially when not cushioned (the former is the reason for shin splints to occur). If that doesn't happen, you do those "flaps" with your foot which are bad for the heads of the metatarsi 1 and 5 and your front arch of the foot.

I'll provide a more theoretical answer that may be generally helpful along my own personal experience which may benefit some.
The Theory:
Whether you subscribe to evolution or creation, you will conclude that the human body is designed for walking and running.  In other words, we can conclude that humans were walking and running long before we invented the footwear we use for our various athletic endeavors today.  With than in mind, we will then also conclude that while walking and running, the human foot is designed to come in parallel contact with the ground.  We may probably also conclude that the human foot was not designed for running on concrete or asphalt as those are more modern inventions. These are the fundamental theories behind zero-drop running shoes. We need something to protect the bottoms of our feet from the hard surfaces we encounter in an urban environment, but shoes should not change the angle at which our feet contact the ground.
We also understand that humans are highly adaptable.  We see this as we run.  Our bodies adapt to the training by developing a more robust cardiovascular system along with stronger bones and muscles.  We have to accept that we have also adapted to our footwear choices.  So an individual who has commonly worn shoes that have a slant between heel and toe, will generally have a tighter achilles tendon and weaker calf muscles than an individual who has lived a barefoot lifestyle.  This does not mean that the individual can not adapt from one to the other, but depending on age and other health factors, they should be careful and patient with the transition.
My own story:
I enjoyed running in high school and was a good distance runner.  I was highly active and had very few injuries or problems.  Over time, I let my health and fitness slip.  I had a wake up call at 37 and began running again.  I used similar running shoes to what I had used in my youth.  Progress was slow at first, but once I turned the corner, I went all in - which resulted in shin splints.  I tried to push through, which led to a stress fracture.  Over the next 2 years I went in and out of injury, spending time doing pool workouts and lots of therapy.  My physical therapist was a triathlete and could see problems with my running form.  He gave me lots of advice and exercises, but I struggled to make any real changes and was constantly re-injuring.
One day I walked into a shoe store and explained my saga to a young salesman, who helped me find good running shoes.  He explained that he could also remove some of the material under the heel, so the shoes would be more level and he explained how that could help.  I wasn't willing to spend extra for that, but found the thought interesting.  As I was checking out, he said, "Do you really want to solve this?"  Of course, I said, "Yes!"  Then he gave me advice that changed everything - "Replace one of your 8 mile runs on the road with a 1 mile slow barefoot jog on grass once per week and then rest."  That was it.
And he was right.  Everything my PT was trying to explain and giving me exercises to correct, was corrected in one minute once I took my shoes off and ran on the grass.  I followed this plan for 2 months, replacing an 8 mile road run with a slow 1 mile jog on the grass each week and always rested the next day.  My achilles had to stretch a little and my calf muscles were a bit sore at first, but I adapted quickly.  What's more important, my running form changed so that my road runs were not causing injury.  I stopped seeing the PT and have run injury free ever since.
That shoe salesman was Golden Harper, who left his dad's shop and started his own shoe company known as Altra Running, which specializes in zero-drop running shoes.  I have been using Altra shoes exclusively for running since the 'Instinct' was introduced and they have worked really well for me for thousands of miles over more than a decade.  You could say I have become a zero-drop convert.
My Conclusion:
Even as an advocate of zero-drop shoes, I always stress that the transition method and timing is VERY important.  A 1 mile jog on the grass may be too far for you and 2 months may not be long enough.  If you decide to transition, give yourself time to make the adjustment and give your body time to adapt.  If you already have something that really works for you, you may not need to make any changes.  I ran track and cross country throughout high school in typical, slanted soles and had no problems whatsoever.  So as an adolescent, I adapted to those shoes and they served me well.  In my late 30s and beyond, my body needed something different and zero-drop shoes have been the solution.

"but shoes should not change the angle at which our feet contact the ground." is a nice way of putting it (rather than the usual focus on heel-v-forefoot striking).  I also like Altras - I've only had a few running injuries since starting running just over two years ago, but none when wearing Altras.

I'm not aware of any actual studies that show if these are an improvement to more traditional shoes. Although I also haven't looked in a few years.
In theory, they train you to run more "naturally" to how humans are supposed to run because they don't give as much leeway when it comes to bad form. So you either adjust your gate to naturally handle striking such that the force of impact is evenly distributed across the foot, or you get injured. You also strengthen the muscles and tendons in the feet to handle forces that you don't get as much exposure to with traditional shoes.
In practice, I think it's more of a survivorship bias involved. The people who  do manage to adjust their gait and learn how to run minimally will benefit from these and say how amazing and spectacular they are. The people who don't will give up and go back to standard running shoes*
Experience has a lot to do with it.  If you've been running for many years, then suddenly swapping to zero drop or other minimalist shoes is going to probably be extremely strenuous on your feet and ankles. It will take a significant amount of time for you to adjust to the new format, and you'll have to run at a fraction of the distance you were originally.
Beginners can run with these without as much issues.  They are learning how to run as it is, so strengthening your feet with zero-drop shoes will probably be more beneficial in the long run.
* Then they go online and say that the shoes didn't help.  Then get banned from the running forums because minimalist runners are weirdly cultish about it.

"Beginners can run with these without as much issues." that definitely was not my experience.  I started with some Vibram five-finger running shoes and almost immediately had severe Achilles problems.  I am fine running in them now, but still only use them occasionally (mostly for working on form - they are really good for awareness of how your foot is landing), but wear less minimalist zero-drop shoes most of the time (mostly Altras), which I like.  IMHO the amount of cushioning is the main issue.

Just adding to the existing excellent answers, it makes a big difference whether they are minimalist zero-drop shoes, or just regular zero-drop shoes.
I have some Vibram V-Runs, like this:

I don't think you could run with a heel-strike in these, because there is no cushioning anywhere, and I tend to be pretty much purely forefoot striking when I run in them.
If you want to run with a fore-foot strike, then I would recommend getting a pair of minimalist shoes like this, because (i) they force you onto the fore-foot and (ii) you can really feel just how your feet are landing because there is no cushioning to deaden the impact, so you get good feedback on changes in your running form.
I also run in Altra running shoes like these:

These are also zero-drop, but they have a 21mm stack height, so there is some cushioning everywhere.  I am a mid-foot striker when I am running in these.  I suspect you could run in them with a heel-strike as well if you wanted to as there is some cushioning under the heel.  The wear pattern on my oldest zero-drop shoes suggests that I have been heel-striking at least some of the time (this is a lot less evident in my newer running shoes).
I started with the Vibrams and very quickly got bad Achilles problems, but soon got the Altras and had no problems at all running in those.  So it is not just zero-drop you need to consider, but also the amount of cushioning.  Altra (and presumably other manufacturers) also make squidgy shoes with large stack heights that are still zero-drop, so if you want to heel strike in zero-drop shoes then you should be able to find something that works for you.
I think it is easier to have a mid- or fore-foot strike in non-minimalist zero-drop shoes, but I am not sure that there is a huge difference between those and low-drop (e.g. 4mm) running shoes in terms of improving your form - but that is just my experience and YMMV.
Note: I opted for zero-drop because I wanted to transition from a mild heel strike to a fore-foot/mid-foot strike because I would rather stress muscles and tendons than joints and ligaments.  It seems to be working, not had any injury problems with Altras, and I can run in the Vibrams now that my Achilles and calves have got used to them a bit more.  Most of the injuries I have had have been from sprinting, where I am definitely fore-foot striking.

We evolved barefoot and likely ran away from predators and toward prey. Here is a resource on the barefoot shoes vs regular running shoes debate: https://bananomad.com/health-and-fitness/barefoot-shoes-vs-regular-shoes-which-is-better-for-you/

Hello there. Link-only answers are frowned upon on the StackExchange network. Relevant content should be embodied on the post on this site with due acknowledgement, as you can read in the help center. That being said, statements like this aren't helpful. The first modern running shoes (Nike) were developed exactly because the maker found the barefoot running style elsewhere so beautiful and asked himself why people in Miami don't run the same way....well they couldn't because you run differently on hard surfaces than in nature.
